# Mailchimp Embeded code not Displaying success message in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mailchimp

I'm using mailchimp classic embedded code in my project to subscribe to a news letter.

When the subscriber button is clicked with empty textboxes the validation is properly working. When I click on it with values in the text boxes the subscription works but it doesn't display the success message. Instead the error list of chrome browser includes this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And the URL is displaying. When I click on this URL this will show the error message in German (as I'm using mailchimp for a german news letter)

```
"{"result":"success","msg":"Fast fertig... Wir m\u00fcssen Ihre E-Mail-Adresse best\u00e4tigen. Um die Anmeldung abzuschlie\u00dfen, klicken Sie bitte auf den Link in der E-Mail, die wir soeben an Sie geschickt haben."}"
```

Translated, it reads:

```
"{"result": "success", "msg":. "Almost finished ... We m \ u00fcssen your e-mail address best u00e4tigen \ To u00dfen the application abzuschlie \, please click on the link in the e-mail that we just sent to you. "}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may very well be the jQuery wrapper issue that Wordpress has with Mailchimp's embedded forms. If this is the case, you could use a plain text editor and in the embedded form code from mailChimp replace the '$' with 'jQuery'.

Wordpress prevents the $ variable from being set, to avoid javascript collisions. They do supply a jQuery wrapper, but that's not real easy to implement. The replacement of $ with jQuery in the embedded form works far easier.